# E/Volley﹕ [194] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for url

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to send a json obj by POST to an api via volley in my android app and capture the json response but i keep getting this error:
 E/Volley﹕ [194] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for http://phoneapi.adro.co/Services/AdService.svc/GetAd .

there is the piece of code that make the request:

```
 public class JsonObjectSend
{
    private static final String TAG_action = "Action";
    private static final String TAG_acValue = "ActionValue";
    private static final String TAG_bg = "BgColor";
    private static final String TAG_id = "CampId";
    private static final String TAG_ctype = "CampType";
    private static final String TAG_adr = "ClickAddress";
    private static final String TAG_endAnim = "EndAnimation";
    private static final String TAG_expText = "ExplainText";
    private static final String TAG_imType = "ImageType";
    private static final String TAG_imgUBanner = "ImageUrlBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgULBanner = "ImageUrlLargBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgUMRect = "ImageUrlMediumRectange";
    private static final String TAG_imgUFBanner = "ImageUrlFullBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgULeadBrd = "ImageUrlLeaderBoard";
    private static final String TAG_logoU = "LogoUrl";
    private static final String TAG_mainText = "MainText";
    private static final String TAG_packName = "PackageName";
    private static final String TAG_repText = "ReplaceText";
    private static final String TAG_startAnim = "StartAnimation";
    private static final String TAG_videoU = "VideoUrl";
    private static final String TAG_type = "type";
    private static final String TAG_atag = "atag";
    private static final String TAG_msg = "message";
    private static final String TAG_pix = "pixel";
    private static final String TAG_scrpt = "script";
    private static final String TAG_tkn = "token";

    public void sendobj()
    {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("DeviceId", "sdasda");
            jsonBody.put("AppId", "ECC7BCE40126408386BCFCF8AB9187E7");
            jsonBody.put("AdType", "text");
            jsonBody.put("Location", "35.7209331,51.472983");
            jsonBody.put("UserOperator", "Irancell");
            jsonBody.put("Ip", "127.0.0.1");
            jsonBody.put("NetworkType", "3G");
            jsonBody.put("DeviceType", "Android");
            jsonBody.put("DeviceBrand", "Samsung");
            jsonBody.put("Width", "0");
            jsonBody.put("Height", "0");
            jsonBody.put("TestMode", "true");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String tag_string_req = "Send_Object";
        JsonObjectRequest Req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.API_URL, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
         {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jObj = response;
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        String action = jObj.getString(TAG_action);
                        String actionvalue = jObj.getString(TAG_acValue);
                        String bg = jObj.getString(TAG_bg);
                        String campid = jObj.getString(TAG_id);
                        String camptype = jObj.getString(TAG_ctype);
                        String clickadr = jObj.getString(TAG_adr);
                        String endanim = jObj.getString(TAG_endAnim);
                        String exptext = jObj.getString(TAG_expText);
                        String imgtype = jObj.getString(TAG_imType);
                        String imgurlbanner = jObj.getString(TAG_imgUBanner);
                        String imgurllargebanner = jObj.getString(TAG_imgULBanner);
                        String imgurlmedrectangle = jObj.getString(TAG_imgUMRect);
                        String imgurlfullbanner = jObj.getString(TAG_imgUFBanner);
                        String imgurlleaderboard = jObj.getString(TAG_imgULeadBrd);
                        String logourl = jObj.getString(TAG_logoU);
                        String maintext = jObj.getString(TAG_mainText);
                        String packagename = jObj.getString(TAG_packName);
                        String replacetext = jObj.getString(TAG_repText);
                        String startenim = jObj.getString(TAG_startAnim);
                        String videourl = jObj.getString(TAG_videoU);
                        String type = jObj.getString(TAG_type);
                        String atag = jObj.getString(TAG_atag);
                        String msg = jObj.getString(TAG_msg);
                        String pixel = jObj.getString(TAG_pix);
                        String script = jObj.getString(TAG_scrpt);
                        String token = jObj.getString(TAG_tkn);
                        Log.d("action", action);
                    } else
                    {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Log.d("Debug", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Log.d("error","Error");
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return params;
            }//

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(Req, tag_string_req);
    }

}//class end
```

and this is my app controller class:

```
   public class AppController extends Application
{

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
    {
        if (mRequestQueue == null)
        {
            //  mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new OkHttpStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(new File(getCacheDir(), "volley")), network);
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack
    {
        private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;
        public OkHttpStack()
        {
            this(new OkHttpClient());
        }

    private  OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
    {
        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                    {
                            new X509TrustManager()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                                @Override
                                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                                @Override
                                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                    };
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        return okHttpClient;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }




        public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client)
        {
            client=getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
            if (client == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
            }
            mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException
        {
            return mFactory.open(url);
        }
    }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag)
    {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req)
    {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag)
    {
        if (mRequestQueue != null)
        {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my full logcat:

```
    06-17 23:20:54.637  14338-14338/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-17 23:20:54.751  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 37 (eng.buildbot-x86) (code 199997)
06-17 23:20:54.757  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/LibraryLoader﹕ Loading: webviewchromium
06-17 23:20:54.758  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 9529-9530)
06-17 23:20:54.758  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
06-17 23:20:54.766  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {39d8cd06}
06-17 23:20:54.767  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
06-17 23:20:54.767  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-17 23:20:54.771  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
06-17 23:20:54.771  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-17 23:20:54.775  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
06-17 23:20:54.776  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=32 off=46092 len=2953
06-17 23:20:54.776  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:33 off:228796 len:643667
06-17 23:20:54.780  14338-14358/ir.adro.adrosdk W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
06-17 23:20:54.787  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-17 23:20:54.788  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-17 23:20:54.797  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-17 23:20:54.806  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa363fc10, tid 14338
06-17 23:20:54.859  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:mailbox_synchronizer.cc(36)] MailboxSync not supported due to missing EGL image/fence support
06-17 23:20:54.871  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
06-17 23:20:54.881  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-17 23:20:54.882  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
06-17 23:20:54.908  14338-14364/ir.adro.adrosdk W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
06-17 23:20:54.910  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-17 23:20:54.912  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-17 23:20:54.980  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-17 23:20:54.980  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa1f9fdc0, tid 14379
06-17 23:20:55.005  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-17 23:20:55.023  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-17 23:20:55.023  14338-14379/ir.adro.adrosdk W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa1fba7a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-17 23:20:55.235  14338-14377/ir.adro.adrosdk E/Volley﹕ [199] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for http://phoneapi.adro.co/Services/AdService.svc/GetAd
06-17 23:20:55.235  14338-14338/ir.adro.adrosdk D/error﹕ Error
```

can anyone tell me why i am keep getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid **307** reponse code by adding `/` at the end of your url, i.e. `http://phoneapi.adro.co/Services/AdService.svc/GetAd/`

Then with the following sample code (I used your `jsonBody`), you should check your web service more since this code will get **400** reponse code instead

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("onResponse", response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
            VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
            volleyError = error;
        }

        return volleyError;
    }
};
```

When debugging (set breakpoint at `VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));`), you will get some information such as

`The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at AdroMobileApi.Services.AdService.GetAd(AdRequest request)
   at SyncInvokeGetAd(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>`

Comment: first of all your answer is awesome! second, you mean I should check my phps? so it is a serverside problem?

Comment: I suggest you check it more to solve 400 not 307. You can search for `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` with php, perhaps some variable is null

Comment: However, after solving 307 issue, if your android code works with the web service (php), of course you don't have to review php code

Answer (score 1):

**response code 307** means **Temporary Redirect**.

Please check your server side for this issue.

[image]

**More Explanation :**

> Server sent this response to directing client to get requested
>   resource to another URI with same method that used prior request. This
>   has the same semantic than the 302 Found HTTP response code, with the
>   exception that the user agent must not change the HTTP method used: if
>   a POST was used in the first request, a POST must be used in the
>   second request.

For more info see : [Response codes for HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes)

Comment: aha, can you give me a hint on how to solve it on server side?