# what is the best solution to resolve temporary redirect error code 307 in volley and retrofit?

Tags: android, redirect, android-volley, retrofit

I resolved this error code 307 issue by hitting first on base url and then getting the redirect url from response header and hitting on that redirect url in both volley and retrofit. In volley I used retry policy to hit on redirect url but in retrofit I handle this redirection manually.

```
   String redirectUrl=responseHeaders.get("location");
```

Is there any best solution to resolve this issue?Please help me out.

Comment: Try adding `/` at the end of your url as my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892945/e-volley-194-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-307-for-ur/37898619#37898619 to see if it can work for your issue or not

Comment: What version of retrofit/okhttp are you using?

Comment: okhttp is 3.2.0 and retrofit 2.0.2.

Comment: @BNK adding / doesnt work for my issue.